# Как передать данные между классами в Java

Tags: java

Пробую писать программу на Java и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
у меня есть массив данных, который я генерирую в классе1, его нужно передать в класс2, изменить данные в нем и вернуть в класс1, чтобы при следующем обращении к нему данные уже были изменены. У меня выходит только передача в класс2, но измененный массив не могу передать обратно. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Приведите код, который у вас уже есть, посмотрим.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, прежде всего стоит понять, что ты работаешь не с классами, а с их экземплярами. И ты не переходишь между классами... а можешь из объекта одного класса вызвать метод объекта другого...

```
ClassOne() {
  private var;

  public void method(){
  var = new ClassTwo().somemethod(array[]);
  }
}
```

Соответственно,после отработки кода данные находятся не в классе ClassOne, а только в его отдельном экземпляре... И, если, на этот экземпляр больше нет никаких ссылок, то все отработанные данные будут попросту уничтожены сборщиком мусора.

Данные хранит не класс, а объект и у объекта есть время жизни. Чтобы сохранить данные на длительное время, можно отправить их в базу данных или записать в фаил...

Answer (score 0):

- Правильней всего будет сделать массив в классе 1 приватным полем и
  содать публичные методы для его изменения, которые будите вызывать в
  классе 2.
- Так же можно создать в классе 1 публичный метод геттер, который будет
  возвращать этот массив, и вызывать этот метод в классе 2, а уже в
  классе 2 менять массив как вам надо.

Answer (score 0):

У вас очень общий вопрос, поэтому приведу **псевдокод**, от которого вы сможете оттолкнуться и написать свой код, причём необязательно так же. Если я правильно вас понял, ваш массив не изменяется (не меняется его размер или тип содержимого, то есть его не надо создавать заново), а меняются лишь сами данные в нём.

```
public class ClassOne {
    private Data[] data;
    private ClassTwo processor; // инициализируйте сетером, конструктором ClassOne или прямо тут

    // какие-то другие поля и методы этого класса

    public void work() {
        if (data == null) {
            this.data = generateData();
        }

        // какой-то другой необязательный код
    }

    private Data[] generateData() {
        Data[] data = ... // дальше код генерации начальных данных

        processor.processData(data);
        return data
    }
}


public class ClassTwo {

    // какие-то поля и методы этого класса

    public void processData(Data[] data) {
        // код обработки данных
    }
}
```

Затем просто вызывайте метод `work()`.